# Trying to connect Eureka and Zuul and I have error

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to study microservices (and docker). Trying to connect Eureka and Zuul and I have error: "com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: eureka-service"

There's my zuul application.properties

```
spring.application.name=ZuulService
server.port=8080

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka-service:9000/eureka
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

and eureka application.properties

```
spring.application.name=EurekaService
server.port=9000

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.net.UnknownHostException: eureka-service

The `eureka-service` host cannot be resolved. This host is coming from

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka-service:9000/eureka
```

of Zuul-service's application.properties.
Give it the IP address of machine where your `eureka-service` is running.
If it's on `localhost`, it would be:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:9000/eureka
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for answering! Another question: should i use localhost, if i'm gonna use docker next?

Comment: @Avartiai `localhost` works with Docker, I think. Else, you can go with `http://<IP address of Docker>:<port>/eureka`. To get docker IP:  `docker-machine ip`.

Comment: @Avartiai: If the above answer helps, you can accept the answer to help others. :)